# How to resume the NER training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy 2.0.6 with an italian NER model.
I would like to add samples to that model to improve accuracy. What is the correct way?

At the beginning i have trained the model with this code:

```
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(epochs):
            random.shuffle(train)
            losses = {}

            for batch in minibatch(train, size=32):
                docs, golds = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(docs, golds, drop=.3, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
```

Unfortunately, It does not work for new samples.
I get an error on the `optimizer = nlp.begin_training()` line.

```
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
  File "/home/damiano/lavoro/python/parser/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 456, in begin_training
    sgd=self._optimizer)
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 843, in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.begin_training
KeyError: 'token_vector_width'
```

How can i "resume" the training of a NER model?

Comment: I also a get an error when training NER in spacy.
AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'resume_training' on line 
optimizer = nlp.resume_training()